# Who owns the copyright to an audio recording of a person playing a public domain song on a musical instrument?

Tags: united-states, copyright

If Bob plays a public-domain song on a musical instrument, and Alice records his performance (no video, just audio), who owns the copyright to the recording? Nothing creative was involved in creating the recording; the goal was to faithfully reproduce the sound of Bob's instrument, not to improve or augment it.

Comment: Was Bob's performance public or private?

Comment: @Greendrake it was in a funeral service at a church. Anyone was allowed to enter.

Comment: You had asked about that in the radio, and the answer there includes this pattern

Comment: I think this basically answers the question: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/13872/3209